# How to check what happened when Xdebug suddenly stopped working?

Tags: symfony, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I created Symfony skeleton which shows my docker containers with Xdebug:
[Repository](https://github.com/Raloriz/xdebug)

At the beginning after installing Xdebug based on this instruction - [guide](https://dev.to/brpaz/docker-phpstorm-and-xdebug-the-definitive-guide-14og), everything worked. Unfortunately, some time later, during programming, it stopped working. How can I check what needs to be repaired or changed?

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/chadrien/c90927ec2d160ffea9c4

Comment: 1) What's your IDE and Xdebug versions? 2) Collect and check Xdebug log (`xdebug.remote_log`) -- it should tell what is happening so can give you the hints as in what direction to look further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check this. `PHP_VERSION => 7.2.3 Xdebug Version => 2.7.1 PHPSTORM => 2019.1.1`. Flug, unfortunately, it didn't work.
Ok, now I have set up `xdebug.remote_log => /tmp/xdebug.log => /tmp/xdebug.log` but i dont know how to find this file.